# List of per-physics engine capabilities/compatibility/known incompatibilities

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a place where one could quickly decide which physics engine to use knowing his requirements (e.g. dynamic changes to models during runtime, joint friction, whatever).

It happens that some functionality is only implemented for ODE, but not the other engines. It would be nice to see all these "TODOs" in one place.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17413/list-of-per-physics-engine-capabilities/compatibility/known-incompatibilities/) by [peci1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/847/peci1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For (Ignition) Gazebo, the list is here: https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/comparison .

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/847/peci1/) with karma: 186 on 2023-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0